# Find the value of $a$ for with $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}e^{na}=2$

Tags: calculus

I was given the following problem and told to find the value of $a$: $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}e^{na}=2$$I understand that the answer to this question will result in 1+ a number that decreases exponentially. It seems to me that $a$ will be a ln function in order to get rid of the $e$. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with geometric series?  And that $(e^{na}) = (e^a)^n$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that when $e^a < 1$, the geometric series tells us:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{na} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (e^a)^n = \frac{1}{1-e^a}$$

so we should solve $$2=\frac{1}{1-e^a}$$ or after some simple manipulations:

$$e^a = \frac{1}{2}$$

giving $$a= -\ln(2)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider the sum of infinite series
$$1+x+x^2+\cdots=\dfrac{1}{1-x}$$
where $|x|<1$. (You can try to plug in $x=e^a$ guaranteed $e^a<1$)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=e^a$,  we can get that $x<1$,  how?  Assume that $x = 1$,  then the series $s=\infty$. The same is true if $x > 0$.

So, lets concluded that $x < 1$,  so we can use sum of  infinite GP,  it will get $a=-\ln(2)$